# certutil: function failed: security library: bad database

Tags: centos, ssl, ssl-certificate, public-key, private-key

when I'm using `certutil` it returns this error: `certutil: function failed: security library: bad database.`

e.g. I can't list certs or keys

How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If it is new system, your certificate database might not be initialized. To fix this, perform:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.pki/nssdb
certutil -d $HOME/.pki/nssdb -N
```

Comment: If you don't want a password on the certificate database, add the `--empty-password` switch to the end of the `certutil` command.

Comment: I found that if I ran instead: `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L` it would not result in that error. But if I just run `certutil -L` it would show that error. Does that mean the database is not corrupted, but there's some incompatibilty or does certutil expect the wrong directory?

Answer (score 8):

In case database already has been initialised, but still is corrupted then it has to be rebuild:

```
$ mv ~/.pki/nssdb ~/.pki/nssdb.corrupted
$ mkdir ~/.pki/nssdb
$ chmod 700 ~/.pki/nssdb
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -N
```

Check if working alright

```
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L
Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
```

Import certificate

```
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n GoAgent -i ~/programs/goagent/local/CA.crt
```

Comment: Since last update of libGNUTLS on Debian my browsers (chrome and iceweasel) failed to open. On console I got `[5284:5310:0306/110217:ERROR:nss_util.cc(750)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018` and no way to solve this gracefully. Rebuilding the DB solved it for me! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I was able to rebuild the DB and list the certificates after that, but my import is still failing with the error: `certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_BAD_DATABASE: security library: bad database.` My import command is `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssb -A -t "CT,C,C" -n sophos -i ~/Downloads/sophos_cert.crt` This shouldn't have to be run as root, should it?

Comment: This fixed an `nss_util.cc` error: `After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018` when starting Google Chrome on an existing user profile that was possibly corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display certifications from a specific folder (for example, the folder which stores the `cert8.db` file for Firefox), you need to specify the folder with "-d":

```
nss-certutil -d /Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/jii912uh.default -L
```

Otherwise, `nss-certutil` may try to read *.db files from `~/.netscape` folder, or maybe `$HOME/.pki/nssdb` as previous user mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the `-d` directory path (must point to the directory) have any space or not. With space it gives the same error or bad file format error - old database format etc. Specially in Mac the folder is in `"Application Support"` which contains space. So have the path fully quoted:

```
"/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/jii912uh.default"
```

or add the \ escape character.

```
 /Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/jii912uh.default
```

And check that the folder have the following files, `cert8.db, key3.db and secmob.db.`

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question, but the mentioned solutions did not work for me, because the error was caused by incorrect shell expansion.

In my case, I had to replace `~` with `$HOME`, e.g.

```
certutil -d sql:~/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n KEY_NAME -i ~/path_to_the_key/key.cert
```

became

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n KEY_NAME -i $HOME/path_to_the_key/key.cert
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved problem using this solution (Windows XP, nss 3.15.1):

```
cd /dir/with/database
C:/full/path/to/certutil.exe -L -d .
```

Comment: That's great, but the question specifies CentOS.