# pkcs11_lib - NSS Initialize Failed (bad database?)

Tags: linux, fedora, nss, smartcard

I'm having trouble getting PKCS#11 and PAM to work, for whatever reason [nss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Security_Services) has stopped working and I can't create a new database.

Here's the output from PKCS11 and NSS:

```
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:187: Initializing NSS ...
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:197: Initializing NSS ... database=/etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:206: NSS_Initialize failed: (null)
ERROR:pam_pkcs11.c:250: Failed to initialize crypto
```

After checking all my configs and howto's I googled and found this: [certutil: function failed: security library: bad database](https://serverfault.com/questions/414578/certutil-function-failed-security-library-bad-database)

Which reminded me that I probably never created a new nss database. *(which, however, I thought would be done automatically?)*

But when trying to create a new database, i get the following:

```
# certutil -d /etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb -N
certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format.
```

So I did some digging and tried:

```
# certutil -d sql:/etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb -N
certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_BAD_DATABASE: security library: bad database.
```

**System:** Fedora 21 (This is as new as it gets)
**NSS:** nss-tools-3.20.1-1.0 + nss-3.20.1-1.0
**PAM:** pam_pkcs11-0.6.8-6
**OpenSC:** opensc-0.14.0-2
**OpenSSL:** openssl-1.0.1k-12
**SqlLite:** sqlite-3.8.11.1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should probably go home and have some food or something.

Forgot to create the folder `nssdb` (yes, it's a folder and not a file.. which is so clearly stated in every forum google came up with during my debugging).

I should know this.

```
# mkdir -p /etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb
# chmod 700 /etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb
# certutil -d /etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb -N
```

Also note that when using NSS with PAM, especially on older systems.
**Never** use `sql:` style nss databases.